# Distribution of hitting time of the integrated CIR process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, probability, term-structure

If an increasing process $X_t$ has a known Laplace transform $\mathbb{E} e^{-s X_t} = m_t(s)$, define its hitting time $\tau$ to some level $B$ to be
$$
\tau = \inf\{ u > 0 : X_u \geq B \}.
$$
Can we express the Laplace transform (or its CDF) of $\tau$ in terms of $m$?

In particular, I am interested in the hitting time of the integrated CIR process
$$
X_t = \int_0^t V_s \ ds
$$
where
$$
dV_t = (\alpha V_t + \beta) dt + \gamma \sqrt{V_t} dW_t.
$$
The Laplace transform of $X_t$ is known in closed-form in this case, and given by
$$
m_t(s) = \mathbb{E} e^{-s X_t} = \left( \frac{e^{-\alpha t/2}}{\cosh(Pt/2)-\frac{\alpha}{P}\sinh(Pt/2)} \right)^{2\beta/\gamma^2} \exp\left(-\frac{s V_0}{P} \frac{2 \sinh(Pt/2)}{\cosh(Pt/2)-\frac{\alpha}{P} \sinh(Pt/2)}\right)
$$
where $P = \sqrt{\alpha^2 + 2 \gamma^2 s}$.

Comment: You may be able to use Dynkan's formula and then numerically integrate the resulting ODE.  I doubt there is a closed form solution.

Answer (score -1):

The Laplace transform of the integrated process CIR process is given by, see e.g. Dufresne (2001). you can download it

1. [The integrated square-root process](http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/3198727f14369487c1256e780050bd87/$FILE/DUFRESNE%20%5B2001%5D.pdf)

Comment: Nice paper. But how does this relate to the Laplace transform of the hitting time?